# How do you install the "Recommended" Windows Updates in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, windows-update

I can see from my antivirus software (ESET) that there are a number of available Windows Updates for drivers and hardware for my PC. In Windows 7 these were easy to install through Windows Update, but in Windows 10 the checkbox to "Include Recommended Updates" has been removed and none of the updates show up in Windows Update itself.

How can I install these updates?

[image]

With reference to the screenshot above, the only updates I'm actually offered through Windows Update are the first two. All the "Recommended" and "Optional" ones are are not shown.

Comment: have you tried the tool that I linked?

Comment: Tryout this simple opensource tool that uses Windows Update Client API to install updates https://github.com/slavanap/Windows10ManualUpdate MS deleted the UI, but API is still there and works perfectly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The option to select which updates/drivers you can install or not is gone, since Windows 10.

But there is a 3rd party tool called [Windows Update MiniTool](http://www.wilderssecurity.com/threads/windows-update-minitool.380535/) which allows to select which updates/drivers can be installed and allows to block updates like you could in former Windows versions.

[image]

> An alternative to the standard Windows Update What you can do:
>  • Check
>   for updates 
>  • Download updates
>  • Installing Updates
>  •
>   Deleting installed updates
>  • Hiding unwanted updates
>  • Get
>   direct links to the *.cab / *.Exe / *.Psf update files • View update
>   history
>  • Configure Automatic Updates
>  • This tool is like the
>   external powershell module PSWindowsUpdate, but much more advanced and
>   user-friendly features
>  • The tool relies and use same WU
>   infrastructure, all downloading are through WU it's not a
>   downloader

Here you can select the drivers that you want to install/update.

Comment: Thanks - just what I needed. I can't believe I need a 3rd party tool to do this!

Answer (score 0):

There is a good way through PowerShell:

1. Download [Windows Update PowerShell Module](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/2d191bcd-3308-4edd-9de2-88dff796b0bc/).
2. Extract the archive.
3. Open your favorite File Manager as Administrator.
4. Navigate to:

   > ```
   > %WINDIR%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
   > ```
5. Copy the folder `PSWindowsUpdate` to that destination.
6. Open PowerShell as Administrator.
7. Edit your profile file, for example with Notepad directly from PowerShell you have opened:

   > ```
   > notepad $PROFILE
   > ```
8. Add this line to file:

   > ```
   > Import-Module PSWindowsUpdate
   > ```
9. Save the file.
10. Close the PowerShell and re-open it, again as Administrator.
11. Finally, you can install all of the updates for example with such command:

    > ```
    >   Get-WUInstall -AcceptAll -Verbose -IgnoreRebootRequired
    > ```
12. You can get more information on the [Windows Update PowerShell Module](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/2d191bcd-3308-4edd-9de2-88dff796b0bc/) page.

Answer (score -1):

- Go to settings and click on Update
- Click on Advanced options under Update Settings
- Tick the box on Give me updates for other Microsoft products when I update Windows.

This will enable optional updates and recommended updates will be installed based on this setting.

Comment: No, I'm not referring to Microsoft updates, I'm referring to the hardware updates shown in my screenshot (from Lexmark and Intel etc). That box is already ticked anyway.